# process.env variables undefined in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I'm reading `undefined` for my enviroment variable.When I console log process.env I can't seem to find the variable I defined In my .env file at the root directory.

**.env.local file**

```
privateKey="444455....."
```

**scripts/hardhat.config.js**

```
mumbai: {
  url: 'https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/3333.....',
  accounts: [process.env.privateKey]
},
```

Is it because I'm reading process.env outside of pages? I aslo tried prefixing like `NEXT_PUBLIC_privateKey="0033....."` and then reading it `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_privateKey` but value would only show inside pages folder and not in scripts/hardhat.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed and initialized the doting NPM package that is needed to use environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

## FINALLY WORKS

I ended up adding the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) AS SOMEONE SUGGESTED and starts reading.

### Note to self

Enviroment variables outside next.js pages need that dotnev thing;